# git cat-file -p master^{tree} errors out in zsh

Tags: git, zsh

In [git-scm.org](http://git-scm.org) documentation, under [git objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) chapter, it uses the command below, but trying it out gives me "zsh: no matches found: master^{tree}".  Any idea what's incorrect?

```
git cat-file -p master^{tree}
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found that when specifying those more tricky git revision parameters, I have to quote them

```
git cat-file -p "master^{tree}"
```

while leaving out the `"` fails.

This behavior and and the reason for it varies with the platform:

- On Windows, in PowerShell and cmd.exe, the `^` character is used for escaping. So, as an alternative, you can write `git cat-file -p master^^{tree}`
- In zsh the `^` character is used for [globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html)
- In bash the command works without quotes

(thanks to Wumpus Q. Wumbley and kostix for explanations)

Comment: Yes, it needs quoting in zsh too. The `^` is a globbing character.

Comment: I tried that before and got fatal: Not a valid object name master^{tree}  My git version is 1.8.2.2.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Only if `extendedglob` is turned on, IIRC.

Comment: Klas, it fails with Git for Windows, under, supposedly, `cmd.exe` because the `^` character is used for escaping in the Windows console shell.

Comment: @Boon, do you really have a branch (or anything) named "master" in your repository? The command works for me with Git 1.8.1.

Comment: The cited command for powershell does not work for me, but the quoted one did.

Comment: If you do get "Not a valid object name master^{tree}", make sure you have at least one commit done. The master branch does not exist yet immediately after `git init`.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `noglob whatever` if you want to run `whatever` without globbing. I have it defined as an alias for `rake`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The various possible cases for this error:

Depending on what shell you use, you may encounter errors when using the master^{tree} syntax.

In CMD on Windows, the ^ character is used for escaping, so you have to double it to avoid this: git cat-file -p master^^{tree}. When using PowerShell, parameters using {} characters have to be quoted to avoid the parameter being parsed incorrectly: git cat-file -p 'master^{tree}'.

If you’re using ZSH, the ^ character is used for globbing, so you have to enclose the whole expression in quotes: git cat-file -p "master^{tree}".

As villasv pointed out that:
"
If you do get "Not a valid object name master^{tree}", make sure you have at least one commit done. The master branch does not exist yet immediately after git init. – villasv
"
Since The master^{tree} syntax specifies the tree object that is pointed to by the last commit on your master branch as referenced to [git object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)
After making commit to current change, `git cat-file -p 'master^{tree}'` can be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Need to clone a project before executing that step in Windows.

Comment: This is barely an answer. Can you give any more explanation on how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what shell you use, you may encounter errors when using the master^{tree} syntax.

In CMD on Windows, the ^ character is used for escaping, so you have to double it to avoid this: git cat-file -p master^^{tree}. When using PowerShell, parameters using {} characters have to be quoted to avoid the parameter being parsed incorrectly: git cat-file -p 'master^{tree}'.

If you’re using ZSH, the ^ character is used for globbing, so you have to enclose the whole expression in quotes: git cat-file -p "master^{tree}".